# Is it possible to join on columns with datatype Text or ntext?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to join on columns with datatype Text or ntext?

Comment: actually it was asked in Interview

Comment: Perhaps they expected you to mention that the `TEXT` dataype is obsolete and has been superseded with VARCHAR(MAX) or to mention **why** on earth they would have to join on `TEXT` data types if the tables are normalized. Other than that, it is possible to use them in a join but you'd have to use an explicit conversion. If that was really the answer they are after, I don't like the question.

Comment: @Lieven: This should be an answer, really. (I mean the "Why on earth...?") +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

NO (without an explicit conversion).

From BOL

> Comparison operators test whether two expressions are the same.
>   Comparison operators can be used on all expressions except expressions
>   of the text, ntext, or image data types.

This code

```
create table #t1 (t text)
create table #t2 (t text)

insert into #t1 values ('1')
insert into #t1 values ('2')
insert into #t1 values ('3')

insert into #t2 values ('1')
insert into #t2 values ('2')

select *
from #t1 t1 
     join #t2 t2 ON t1.t=t2.t

----this works    
    --select *
    --from #t1 t1 
    --   join #t2 t2 ON cast(t1.t as varchar(max))=cast(t2.t as varchar(max))

drop table #t1
drop table #t2
```

gives the error:

```
The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```